# Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter not working on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, drivers, usb

My recently bought Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter (usb) does not connect. However I have another adapter with the same name  which I bought some months ago which works just after plunging in. I tried the one that's not working in Ubuntu on a Windows 7 machine and it worked. So, I am not sure what's wrong with the device.

The outputs of the commands I tried.

`lsusb:
Bus 002 Device 086: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 016: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter`

`dmesg:
[ 2208.272445] mt7601u 2-6:1.0: Error: RX urb failed:-71
[ 2208.272501] mt7601u 2-6:1.0: Error: MCU resp urb failed:-71
[ 2208.272506] mt7601u 2-6:1.0: Error: MCU resp evt:0 seq:5-4!
[ 2208.276732] mt7601u 2-6:1.0: Error: RX urb failed:-71
[ 2208.276957] mt7601u 2-6:1.0: Error: MCU resp urb failed:-71
[ 2208.276961] mt7601u 2-6:1.0: Error: MCU resp evt:0 seq:5-4!
[ 2208.280919] mt7601u 2-6:1.0: Error: RX urb failed:-71
[ 2208.281165] mt7601u 2-6:1.0: Error: MCU resp urb failed:-71
[ 2208.281170] mt7601u 2-6:1.0: Error: MCU resp evt:0 seq:5-4!
[ 2208.285196] mt7601u 2-6:1.0: Error: RX urb failed:-71
[ 2208.285443] mt7601u 2-6:1.0: Error: MCU resp urb failed:-71
[ 2208.285447] mt7601u 2-6:1.0: Error: MCU resp evt:0 seq:5-4!
[ 2208.289445] mt7601u 2-6:1.0: Error: RX urb failed:-71
[ 2208.289659] mt7601u 2-6:1.0: Error: MCU resp urb failed:-71
[ 2208.289662] mt7601u 2-6:1.0: Error: MCU resp evt:0 seq:5-4!
[ 2208.289665] mt7601u 2-6:1.0: Error: mt7601u_mcu_wait_resp timed out
[ 2208.511475] mt7601u 2-6:1.0: Vendor request req:07 off:0080 failed:-71
[ 2208.707474] mt7601u 2-6:1.0: Vendor request req:02 off:0080 failed:-71
[ 2208.907509] mt7601u 2-6:1.0: Vendor request req:02 off:0080 failed:-71`

Comment: What happens if you plug in only one Ralink adapter at a time?

Comment: The one that I bought earlier works. The one I bought recently doesn't.

Comment: It's broken then.